# Image Recognition

Tags: cocoa

I want to write an application in cocoa that recognize an image, for example a square.
example: I take a photo and the application try to find a black square into it

Is there any library or reference to start with for cocoa?

Comment: Which OS? iphone? mac?
Which Lang? objc? C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This blog post on how the iPhone app "Sudoku Grab" works is pretty phenomenal, and should give you a clue as to where you should start.  http://sudokugrab.blogspot.com/2009/07/how-does-it-all-work.html

Answer (score 1):

You might start by getting a subscription to the journal, "[Pattern Recognition and Image Analysis](http://www.springer.com/computer/computer+imaging/journal/11493)."

Answer (score 1):

If what you are trying to achieve is the same sort of pattern recognition as required for 2D barcodes and 3D QR Codes, then you can also check the ZXing library over at http://code.google.com/p/zxing/

Answer (score 0):

[IQEngine](http://www.iqengines.com/) is good api for image recognition for iphone and android.